# Install office365 inside Window Container by Dockerfile and ODT

Tags: docker, window, dockerfile, office365, ms-office

I tried to install excel (or office 365) inside Window container by Dockerfile and ODT (Office Deployment Tool).
This is my `dockerfile` :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016

# Install Office deployment tool
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/7/A/27AF1BE6-DD20-4CB4-B154-EBAB8A7D4A7E/officedeploymenttool_11901-20022.exe C:/deploymenttool_autoextract.exe
RUN C:/deploymenttool_autoextract.exe /quiet /passive /extract:C:

COPY installconfig.xml C:

# Install Office
RUN C:/setup.exe /configure installconfig.xml

ENTRYPOINT powershell
```

And my install file `installconfig.xml`:

```xml
<Configuration>
  <Add
       OfficeClientEdition="64"
       Channel="Broad" >
    <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
   <Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />  
  <Logging Level="Standard" Path="%temp%" /> 
</Configuration>
```

Building container stucks hours at install office. I think the problem comes from my `installconfig.xml` file.

Any advice is welcome!

[image]

Comment: I'm on a Ubuntu machine, so I'm unable to build this image, but can you try with `RUN C:/setup.exe /configure C:/installconfig.xml` instead of `RUN C:/setup.exe /configure installconfig.xml`? Just wondered if the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-office-deployment-tool) did not use the full path for the config file because the command was being executed from the same folder.

Comment: Did you try to run ```C:/setup.exe /configure installconfig.xml``` manually, outside of the Dockerfile? Maybe it requires user input, and in Dockerfile should be run with some flags. Also, maybe there is verbosity flags, that will help find issue.